# How do you configure sails + tailwindcss to work together

Tags: sails.js, tailwind-css, postcss

I've been trying to use [TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/) for the styling of a brand new [SailsJS](https://sailsjs.com/get-started) site.

Referencing the pre-built css from the [tailwind CDN](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#using-tailwind-via-cdn) works fine, but in order to customize the css and bring the css size down for production I need to use the full asset pipeline to build tailwind.

The problem I've run into is that [tailwind recommends PostCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors) ([tailwind also recommends PostCSS here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#process-your-css-with-tailwind)) but [sailsjs uses grunt by default](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/assets/task-automation). In theory I can configure SailsJS to to run PostCSS but I spent a long time trying and my lack of knowledge of the pieces means I've yet to get it all working.

https://github.com/jeffjewiss/sails-hook-postcss looked like it might solve the problem but I couldn't get it working.

Has anyone got these two working together, and how did you do it? Public repository links would be greatly appreciated.

---

These are my various unfinished and not yet working attempts at all the pieces, plus other related resources:

- https://github.com/timabell/spike-sails
- https://github.com/timabell/spike-sails-gulp
- https://github.com/timabell/sails-tailwind
- https://dev.to/chrisfinnigan/setting-up-grunt-and-tailwindcss-2p1h

Comment: This might hold the answer https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-setup-examples/pull/97/commits/377beee15972251cc1ab9d265f8297ebbe52e45b

Comment: Yep that worked with minor modification, see the PR comments for modifications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full setup is available here https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-setup-examples/pull/97

Reproduced here:

```sh
npm i --save-dev tailwindcss grunt-postcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwind init
```

`/assets/styles/tailwindcss/tailwind.css`:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

`tasks/config/postcss.js`:

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.config.set("postcss", {
    options: {
      map: true,
      processors: [require("tailwindcss")("./tailwind.config.js")],
    },
    dist: {
      expand: true,
      cwd: "assets/styles/tailwindcss",
      src: ["tailwind.css"],
      dest: ".tmp/public/styles",
      ext: ".css",
    },
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-postcss");
};
```

`tasks/register/compileAssets.js`:

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.registerTask("compileAssets", [
    "clean:dev",
    "less:dev",
    "copy:dev",
    "postcss", // add this one
  ]);
};
```

`tasks/register/syncAssets.js`

```js
  grunt.registerTask("syncAssets", [
    "less:dev",
    "copy:dev",
    "postcss", // add this one
  ]);
```

```
sails lift
```